# how can I create 508 compliant radio groups and radio buttons using iText version 7.0

Tags: java, itext, radio-button, radio-group, section508

The issue I am running into is when I create a radio button group and it's corresponding radio buttons, screen readers like Jaws are refusing to read out the Radio Button Group name/label/value before the radio button value.

ideally a screen reader like JAWS would read the following radio group + radio buttons like this every time a user tabs to a new radio button. Below is a pseudo example of the code.

Radiogroup name/label: "Are there any guests coming?"

radio button one - "Yes"

radio button two - "No"

The above should read like this every time a user tabs to a radio button:

"Are there any guests coming? radio button yes, one of two radio buttons"

"Are there any guests coming? radio button no, two of two radio buttons"

or something along those lines where it's announcing the name/label of the radio group in addition to the value of the radio buttons + the normal JAWs stuff like identifying what number of radio buttons in the group it's currently tabbed to.

I have tried iText's accessibleProperties class and adding "actualText" and "setAlternateDescription" but, I haven't been able to get anything to pick up in JAWS, the screen reader.

What ends up happening is it just reads the value of the radio button and skips the Radio Group name/Label, and it definately doesn't mention it when you tab to another radio button, you're just getting that radio button's value read out by the screen reader.

I was expecting when a user tabs to a radio button in the radio group, that the radio group name/label will be read out loud in addition to the radio button value.